# SQL parcel query

Tags: sql

I have a parcel table in postgreSQL db that I need to query out specific parcels. 3 fields - mun,block,lot

```
mun1: block 46 and lot 2

mun2: block 1 and lot 1.1
      block 2 and lot 6
      block 2 and lot 7
      block 5 and lot 2
      block 11 and lot 1

mun3: block 11 and lot 2
      block 11 and lot 2.2
      block 7 and lot 2
      block 8 and lot 2
```

I can query each one at a time but I cannot figure out how to do them in one query...any suggestions with syntax and logic

ex:

```
select * from parcels where mun = 'mun1' and block = '46' and lot = '2'
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Your question is not clear I think.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis check edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select * from parcels 
where (mun = 'mun1' and block = '46' and lot = '2')
or (mun = 'mun2' and
    (block = '1' and lot = '1.1'
    or block = '2' and lot = '6'
    or block = '2' and lot = '7'
    or block = '5' and lot = '2'
    or block = '11' and lot = '1'
     )
)
or (mun = 'mun3' and 
    (block = '11' and lot = '2'
     or block = '11' and lot = '2.2'
     or block = '7' and lot = '2'
     or block = '8' and lot = '2'
    )
)
```

Comment: okay yes, this is sort of the logic I was going for I will give this a try

Comment: probably simpler to create a temp table/table variable with the values you want and do an inner join

Comment: @MarshallTigerus would you care to share your answer?